# Does uniformly bounded derivative over a domain imply uniformly bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, compactness

A counterexample is

Consider the domain $D = [1, \infty]$ and consider the function $f(x) = \ln(x)$, then certainly $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$ for all $x \in D$, but there does not exist a $C < \infty$ such that $f(x) \leq C$ for all $x \in D$.

What if the domain is compact? Can anyone give a counterexample or is the following statement correct?

Consider $f: D \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$. If $D$ is compact and $\frac{\partial
 f(x)}{\partial x_i} \leq C$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$ and all $x \in D$, then $f(x) \leq C'$ for all $x \in D$ for some $C' < \infty$ ?

Edit: I am assuming there is a vector version of Lagrange mean value theorem. Choose a point $x_0 \in D$ so that $f(x_0) < \infty$. Then for any $x \in D$, there exists an $x' \in D$ between $x_0$ and $x$ such that (by mean value theorem)
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(x_0) &= \nabla f(x')^T (x-x_0) 
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
\big | f(x) - f(x_0) \big | &\leq \|\nabla f(x')\|_2 \|x-x_0\|_2 
\end{align}
By assumption of bounded domain as well as bounded gradient, we have
\begin{align}
\big | f(x) - f(x_0) \big |  \leq C'
\end{align}
for some $C' < \infty$ and for all $x \in D$. This in turn implies $$|f(x)| \leq C' + |f(x_0)|$$
for all $x \in D$.

Comment: Differentiable implies continuous, and a continuous function on a compact domain is bounded, right?

Comment: yeah it is true maybe. I used MVT to write a short proof. I think it was a trivial question. Nevermind. I will leave the question here instead of deleting it.